# The GestureDetector does not work (example from android developer)

Tags: android, gesture

I am reading the gesture in android at android developer, and following the tutorial I tried to run the following codes:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnGestureListener, OnDoubleTapListener {

    private static final String DEBUG_TAG = "Gestures";
    private GestureDetectorCompat mDetector;

    // Called when the activity is first created.
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        View v = new RelativeLayout(this);
        v.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        setContentView(v);
        mDetector = new GestureDetectorCompat(this, this);
        mDetector.setOnDoubleTapListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        this.mDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent event) {
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "onDown: " + event.toString());
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent event1, MotionEvent event2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "onFling: " + event1.toString() + event2.toString());
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent event) {
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "onLongPress: " + event.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "onScroll: " + e1.toString() + e2.toString());
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onShowPress(MotionEvent event) {
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "onShowPress: " + event.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent event) {
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "onSingleTapUp: " + event.toString());
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent event) {
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "onDoubleTap: " + event.toString());
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "onDoubleTapEvent: " + event.toString());
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent event) {
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "onSingleTapConfirmed: " + event.toString());
        return true;
    }
}
```

The codes came from the site [here](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector.html#detect).

But when I ran the app, I got no debug information when I click or long press the view.

BTW, I test the app in both emulator and htc e1 device.

What is the problem?

Comment: I am appreciate the one re-vote-up my post. Thanks.

Comment: Google never had a strong, reliable documentation. They always have sample code that never works/wrong/buggy. You have to visit sites like this to verify if their sample is correct.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are creating a GestureDetector but you are never "hooking it up" to your View.
Try changing your onCreate like this:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
View v = new RelativeLayout(this);
v.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
setContentView(v);
mDetector = new GestureDetectorCompat(this, this);
mDetector.setOnDoubleTapListener(this);
v.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent me){
        return mDetector.onTouchEvent(me);
    }
});
```

Comment: But I have `override` the `OnTouch` Event for the acivity. Is it not enough?

Comment: I think you have to override `dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent me)` instead of `onTouchEvent()` if you want to do it without a listener on the View itself.

Comment: This worked for me once I @Override dispatchTouchEvent instead of onTouchEvent.

Answer (score 4):

Little late, but my solution of this problem is:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    this.mDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

The return of the Detector gone lost.
Change to:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (this.mDetector != null) return this.mDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
   return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

But is this a good solution? Time for Android Insider. ;)

Tschau Fred

Answer (score 0):

I edited your first line:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnGestureListener, OnDoubleTapListener {
```

I used your code but supplied the full interface names like so:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements GestureDetector.OnGestureListener,     GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener {
```

This worked after the edits. Hope this helps.

Comment: When I tried this, the "GestureDetector" is underlined red, error in Eclipse. Error message "GestureDetector cannot be resolved to a type"

Answer (score 0):

***Here is simple Android Code for gesture direction detection***:

> MainActivity.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.gesture.Gesture;
import android.gesture.GestureLibraries;
import android.gesture.GestureLibrary;
import android.gesture.GestureOverlayView;
import android.gesture.GestureOverlayView.OnGesturePerformedListener;
import android.gesture.GestureStroke;
import android.gesture.Prediction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements
        OnGesturePerformedListener {

    GestureOverlayView gesture;
    GestureLibrary lib;
    ArrayList<Prediction> prediction;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        lib = GestureLibraries.fromRawResource(MainActivity.this,
                R.id.gestureOverlayView1);
        gesture = (GestureOverlayView) findViewById(R.id.gestureOverlayView1);
        gesture.addOnGesturePerformedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onGesturePerformed(GestureOverlayView overlay, Gesture gesture) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ArrayList<GestureStroke> strokeList = gesture.getStrokes();
        // prediction = lib.recognize(gesture);
        float f[] = strokeList.get(0).points;
        String str = "";

        if (f[0] < f[f.length - 2]) {
            str = "Right gesture";
        } else if (f[0] > f[f.length - 2]) {
            str = "Left gesture";
        } else {
            str = "no direction";
        }
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), str, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

}
```

> activity_main.xml

```
<android.gesture.GestureOverlayView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android1="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:android2="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/gestureOverlayView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android1:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Draw gesture"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</android.gesture.GestureOverlayView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank Rahul Raina,

your solution works like a charme for me. However when I tried to generate a signed apk in order to deploy to other devices I got the same error as xpagesbeast: the "GestureDetector" is underlined red, error in Android Studio. Error message "GestureDetector cannot be resolved to a type" –

I just used an explicit cast to (int) in the following line and this made it work and I could build the apk:

```
lib = GestureLibraries.fromRawResource(DisplayPersonByIDActivity.this,
            (int)R.id.gestureOverlayView1);
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found was to call `setClickable(true)` on the view.

It seems that even though you will get touch events okay, the gesture detectors won't do anything unless the view is marked as clickable.

Calling `setOnClickListener()` also works. It seems to also mark the view as clickable.

Answer (score 0):

If you followed Android developer docs I found @FoamyGuy comment in his own answer to work perfect:

Change

```
    override fun onTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
    mDetector.onTouchEvent(event)
    return super.onTouchEvent(event)
    }
```

for

```
    override fun dispatchTouchEvent(ev: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
    mDetector.onTouchEvent(ev)
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev)
}
```