# No suitable constructor found for GestureDetectorCompat

Tags: android

When i Run my code in android studio, the following error message is displayed

> no suitable constructor found for GestureDetectorCompat

What does this mean and how do i solve this issue?

```
This is part of the code,see below  

com.example.curtis.swiperdiaper;

 import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.Menu;
 import android.view.MenuItem;
 import android.widget.TextView;
 import android.view.MotionEvent;
 import android.view.GestureDetector;
 import android.support.v4.view.GestureDetectorCompat;

private TextView ccMessage;
 //the below is causing an error //
"private GestureDetectorCompat gestureDetector;"
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ccMessage = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.ccMessage);
    this.gestureDetector = new GestureDetectorCompat();
}
```

Comment: post the code causing the issue

Comment: have seen other SO questions about the subject ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16452627/the-gesturedetector-does-not-work-example-from-android-developer

Comment: @MauricioGracia- thanks i will have a look

Comment: @Blackbelt - how do i post up the code ?

Comment: copy it from android studio, edit your question, and paste it

Comment: @ Blackbelt - can you give me an example of how to post code . i dont want to do it incorrectly ^_^ . i am new to this so i am learning the do's and don't on stackflow.

Comment: @MauricioGracia - had a look at the link but still having the same issues :(

Comment: @Blackbelt - i have posted the code

Answer (score 0):

What that message means is you are calling the method without parameters and there are no constructor that match that condition (signature)

According to this documentation

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/GestureDetectorCompat.html

There are 2 constructors one that take 2 parameters and one which takes 3

One way to solve this is to add `implements OnGestureListener` to your view or activity. for example

```
Class MyActivity extendes Activity implements OnGestureListener
```

And from your view or activity create the gestureDetector like this

```
this.gestureDetector = new GestureDetectorCompat(this,this);
```

The first parameter is a `Context` and the second is a class that `implements OnGestureListener` in these they are the same class and that is the reason we pass this as both parameters